# Liferay LDAP mappings

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am encountering a problem where I am not able to map LDAP attributes to LR User attributes, which are not available in Control Panel (for example "comments").

For example, if I map LDAP attribute 'department' to LR User model attribute jobTitle, it **works**:

```
ldap.user.mappings=jobTitle=department
```

Now if I want to read the same attribute to a field which is not configurable through CMS then it **does not work** (meaning that the value is never assigned):

```
ldap.user.mappings=comments=department
```

I have also tried custom mappings which also **does not work**. 
Created a custom attribute by the name userDepartment to User object.
And the corresponding mapping in portal-ext.properties:

```
ldap.user.custom.mappings=userDepartment=department
```

So in a nutshell - I am able to map any field coming from LDAP to LR User attributes which are shown in Control Panel (screenname, firstname, lastname, password, jobtitle, mail etc) but not to other LR User attributes (comments, custom attributes).

Sidenote: The problem is not related to portal-ext.properties not being read (updated). In every test scenario the previous LDAP settings have been deleted so they would be read from portal-ext.properties again. The fact that properties are correct has been verified from portalpreferences table.

**Liferay version 6.2.10 EE**

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you working with? Please turn on debugging  for the LDAP import classes under Control Panel -> Server Administration -> Log Levels. 1. Set Log Levels to "ALL" for the following: 
"com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LDAPAuth", 
"com.liferay.portal.security.ldap", 
"com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPUtil"
    2. Click the "Add Category" Button 
    3. Add "com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporter" with the "ALL" Log Levels 4. Check the logs.

Comment: Added the LR version to the question. I will try logging the LR ldap classes tomorrow. I have actually tried 'com.liferay.portal.security.ldap' and couldn't see much in there. I'd assume this fix is not in our current version yet: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-50483

Comment: We had a slightly different issue with importing dynamic attributes in Oracle Virtual Directory. Other regular LDAP attributes were bieng imported in to custom fields for us. We use the same version of LR but slightly more specific 6.2 EE sp2 bundle. We worked with Liferay support on our issue. Looks like you are a LR enterprise customer and should be able to open a ticket for the issue.